# POSTing with $.ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well, the problem is not new, as I saw (really surf a lot), but still can not find solution for myself.

*Description of problem:*

1. Have local Web server - XAMPP;
2. Firefox 29.0.1
3. And trying to send POST with $.ajax

   ```
   function checkUser(){
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'ajax/checkUser.php',
       data: 'uname='+$("#username").val()+'&pword='+$("#password").val(),
       success: function(){
         someNewFunc();
       },
     });
   };
   ```

This function I'm calling with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".button.postfix.login").on("click", function(){
        if (($("#username").val() != "") && ($("#password").val() != "")) {
            hide(); <-- hide pop ups about empty field
            checkUser();    
        } else {$("#empty").show();} <-- pop ups 
        });
    });
```

And here code of page with elements:

```
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />

<a class="button postfix login" href="#" 
onclick="event.preventDefault();">Sign in</a>
```

I guess that data are going out, but the page checkUser.php doesn't get anything. 
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. checkUser.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Result - Array ( )

P.P.S. By the way, if POST change to GET it's working, but need to be POST

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting anything?" Can you post your backend code that receives it? Also, just to verify, your onclick= attribute isn't preempting the jquery onclick function? You've verified the .on is running?

Comment: How do you check the value anyways? Since you're not passing any data on success or alerting on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".button.postfix.login").on("click", function() {

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

if ((username != "") && (password != "")) {
    hide(); <-- hide pop ups about empty field
    checkUser(username, password); // Pass the variables here as a parameter
} else {
    $("#empty").show();} <-- pop ups 
});

// Put the parameters here
function checkUser(username, password) {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/checkUser.php',
    data: { username:username, password:password} //It would be best to put it like that, make it the same name so it wouldn't be confusing
    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
    },
  });
};
```

});

So when you're gonna call it on php

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

echo $username;
```

Comment: Nothing new... the same empty array =(

Comment: How did you check the data? Can you change the code above on ajax and the same as php?

Comment: Just not adding simple `alert(data);` on success - that's was my biggest mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Does your `someNewFunc` callback fire? Do you see the HTTP AJAX request in the developer console in Firefox?

Try sending your post data as a dictionary to `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    uname: $("#username").val(),
    pword: $("#password").val()
  }
});
```

Comment: No, it's doesn't work. And I used `preventDefault` in this project already - everything is ok with this part

Comment: Yeah, I just tested `event` inside of an `onclick` works fine.

Comment: How are you seeing the output of `Array ()` on `checkUser.php`? In the browser console? Remember `$.ajax` does not redirect the browser.

Comment: I can open link in console or just use FireBug, Chrome

Comment: Opening the link from the console does not resend the POST data. In FF when looking at the console right-click and choose to log HTTP responses. Does the output of the actual ajax request look different?

Comment: PHP is horrible. I'm dealing with the same issue. You'll have to use $.post instead. Do that and your PHP will be able to read the value in the $_POST